# How to convert csv to parquet in Azure datafactory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, parquet

I am trying to convert csv to parquet file in Azure datafactory.

One naïve approach would be to create a databricks notebook (File can be read and convert csv to parquet format) and calling that notebook inside a datafactory.

Is there any other elegant way to convert csv to parquet file in datafactory? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a simple field-by-field mapping w/o transformation, use the Copy Activity. If you need to do some data conversation, then use a Data Flow activity. In both cases, source is CSV and sink is Parquet.